# Outputting response of curl request

Tags: bash, curl

I wrote a bash function which made a PUT request and printed the response as such:

```
foo() {
  echo "$(curl --request PUT "foo.com" ...)"
}
```

When I call this function from my shell, I only see the progress table (not the response). How do I fix my function so that it outputs the response of my PUT request ?

Comment: Are you sure the request actually returns output?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I get a response when I execute the curl command in the shell.

Comment: This can happen if the command alters its behavior depending on whether `stdout` goes to a terminal or not. But AFAIK, the only thing `curl` does is omit the progress bar when it's not going to a terminal.

Comment: `echo "$(command)"` is mostly equivalent to just writing `command`. Why do you need `echo`?

Comment: I want to see the response of my request in the standard output.

Comment: That's what `curl` does if you don't wrap it in `$()`, as in lojza's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner. Works for me.

```
foo() { curl -o - -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": 1}' https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 ; }
```